# Why are certain keyboard shortcuts not working through Microsoft Office Communicator 2007 R2 desktop sharing?

Tags: office-communicator-2007

**Context**

I connected to a colleague's desktop via Office Communicator 2007 R2 (he gave me control over his computer) and I had a look at his [Eclipse IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) to show him a few things.

[image]

**Problem**

The problem is that not all keyboard shortcuts seem to work through the "desktop sharing" feature.
<kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd> for maximizing an Eclipse view worked.
<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+T</kbd> for "Open Type" did not work.

**Question**

I was wondering why that is. Does anyone know?

1. Does Office Communicator simply not relay all keyboard shortcuts, but only certain ones? Meaning it's not possible at all to send <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+T</kbd> over the wire?
2. Or did I just do something wrong?
3. Any other reason?

Answer (score 2):

I assume as it's a conflict.

Control M pauses or restarts video.

[Office Communicator 2007 R2 Keyboard Shortcuts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/communicator-help/office-communicator-2007-r2-keyboard-shortcuts-HA010289966.aspx)

Comment: A conflict. Had the same thought. Good to get the confirmation from you. So that means all the keyboard shortcuts found on that site you liked to, won't work. However, it's a little strange that Ctrl+M actually works even though its "Pause/Restart video". Ctrl+Shift+T is the one not working which might be a conflict with "Transfer call".

Comment: Maybe Communicator software is smart enough to realize that the eclipse is not a video so it disregards the command? Where as Transfer a call can be requested regardless of open software on the client machine.

Comment: Is this still an issue for you?

Comment: Not a big one. I don't use Office Communicator that often, and when I use it, I can use the mouse instead of the keyboard shortcuts.